# Android imagebutton not change color when state pressed

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have in my layout a button, which is has to change image when pressed. I Have a selector xml. Here is button:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cwcfwdvcs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_unactive"
            android:drawable="@drawable/add_to_favorites"
            android:text="Favotites"/>
```

Here is selector add_to_favorites.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active"
      android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_unactive" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the button selector state like the following code i.e(res/drawable/button.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"   android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active">

</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active">

</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_to_favorites_active">        

</item>
</selector>
```